# Photoshop composite image formula

Tags: image-processing, photoshop

Photoshop can be used to pack game textures.
Some textures need to be present as greyscale images only.

A common practice is therefore to paste different images into the different A, R, G and B channels as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWJYmL_msXI).

I would like to know the formula behind how Photoshop implements it.

It seems to be somewhat like this, but it isn't completely the same.

```
                bData(pBits) = Sqr( _
                    0.299 * aData(x + 2) * aData(x + 2) + _
                    0.587 * aData(x + 1) * aData(x + 1) + _
                    0.114 * aData(x + 0) * aData(x + 0))
```

I would therefore like to ask what the correct formula is that Photoshop uses to combine the channels into a new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no formula involved. That would not make any sense as your game cannot know which software you used to create that image and hence would not be able to compensate any software-specific channel weights.

You only need those weights if you want to alter colour balance or if you want to convert from RGB to grayscale. It is not related to and not used in saving image files.

In standard raw mode PNG simply stores 4 values per pixel. Photoshop will simply take one value from each layer.

Please read the [PNG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/) if you're interested in any details.

Comment: Yes, I mean the conversion from RGB to grayscale. When I paste a color image into an image channel in Photoshop, it converts it to greyscale. I would like to know the formula behind that.